# Cannot append String to argument in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a very simple function in Python which takes in a website as an argument and simply returns that same website with 'sitemap.xml' added to the end of it.

Ultimately I want to build a web parser, but before I can do that, I have to make sure that sitemap.xml is added to the argument that is passed in.

```
def webparser(website):

    if 'sitemap.xml' not in website:
        website + '/sitemap.xml'

    print(website)

webparser(https://example.com)
```

The website variable should be "https://example.com/sitemap.xml"

However, print(website) only returns
"https://example.com"

Is there any way to change the function so that print(website) returns: https://example.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: You need to assign the result of the string concatenation to some variable, if you want to keep it. Right now you just throw it away...

Comment: To complete @DanMašek 's answer: You are missing a `=` after your `+` operator

Comment: Either make it `website = website + '/sitemap.xml'` or `website += '/sitemap.xml'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
def webparser(website):

    if 'sitemap.xml' not in website:
        website = website + '/sitemap.xml'

    print(website)

webparser(https://example.com)
```

You have forgotten to add the equal sign so “/site map.xml” is getting added to the ‘website’ variable but it is not assigned to any variable.